# python django how to get query I want

Tags: django, django-models

Imagine I have such model

```
class Data(models.Model):
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    phrase = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

I also have two lists: 'blacklist', 'allowed_list'

I need to get Data objects in which disease is IN allowed_list & phrase NOT IN blacklist (both conditions). How can I get this query?

Answer (score 2):

Just like you describe it.

```
Data.objects.filter(disease__in=allowed_list).exclude(phrase__in=blacklist)
```